# Why is the Razor parser complaining about a tag being left open?

Tags: c#, razor

It is saying I need to properly close my div tags.  But they are opened and closed properly unless I am just completely missing something here.

Anyone familiar with why I might be getting this error?

```
<div id="attachments" class="popoversample">
    <h3>
        Attachments</h3>
    <div class="peoplelist">
        @foreach (var item in Model.documents)
        {
            <div class="peoplewrapper">
                <div class="thumb">
                    <img src="../../Images/thumbs/doc.png" alt="" /></div>
                <div class="peopleinfo">
                    <h4>
                        <a href="~/Documents/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.path)" target="_blank">
                    </h4>
                    <img src="../../Images/thumbs/doc.png" alt="" /></a> <span class="filename">@item.filename</span>

                    <ul>
                        <li><span>Followers:</span> 10 &nbsp;/&nbsp; <span>Following:</span> 21</li>
                        <li><span>Member:</span> April 2011</li>
                        <li><span>Skype:</span> johndoe</li>
                        <li><span>Phone:</span> +44033 0400 332</li>
                        <li><span>Address:</span> Something St., Some City, Place 4023</li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
            <!--peoplewrapper-->
            }
    </div>
</div>
```

Error: Parser Error Message: Encountered end tag "div" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?

Comment: Well, you do have some malformed html on a cursory glance: `<a></h4><img /></a>`

Comment: @EricHotinger that was it, not sure how I had that misplaced a tag.

Comment: Cool. I posted mine as an answer as well - but it looks like Eoin spotted it too. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your HTML, there's an error here; the h4 should not end in the middle of an anchor.

```
<a href="~/Documents/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.path)" target="_blank">
                    </h4>
                    <img src="../../Images/thumbs/doc.png" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: since you had the answer in the comment I'll mark this one.  Thanks everyone tho!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this `<a>` tag might be causing the problem.

```
<a href="~/Documents/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.path)" target="_blank">
```

I presume the closing `</h4>` should be moved down a line below the image/span and closing `</a>` tag

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET you can open a tag inside the block and must close it too before opening a new one.

Your code seems pretty bug free! But you need to remember that you need to close the block of div or the server side language before you start something new.

Else this error might pop up. Now the issue there might be in the `peopleWrapper`.

One more bug that is present is. You can see this:

```
<h4>
 <a href="~/Documents/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.path)" target="_blank">
</h4>
 <img src="../../Images/thumbs/doc.png" alt="" /></a>
```

You are opening an `<h4>` block but closing it before closing the `<a>`. You should check all the links or codes present there. The issue can be closing opening of any tag.

Answer (score 1):

The real issue is here (simplified version to highlight the structure):

```
<h4>
    <a>
</h4>
<img /></a>
```

The `<a>` tag is not properly closed, because of where the `h4` closes. Maybe you meant to have:

```
<h4>
    <a href="~/Documents/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.path)" target="_blank">
        <img src="../../Images/thumbs/doc.png" alt="" />
        <span class="filename">@item.filename</span>
    </a>
</h4>
```